# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification with nested ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am using Custom `ListView` with `BaseAdapter`. My custom `ListView` contains another custom `ListView` so I am calling another `BaseAdapter` on `getView()`. It is displaying data perfectly but when I touch on any item on nested `ListView`, app crashes and it is showing below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131296379, class com.amibiotech.dynamin.NonScrollListView) with Adapter(class com.amibiotech.dynamin.MyOrderProducts)]
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Do you want to expend list view data. why not use expendable list view ?

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan, I am showing Products data in nested `ListView`. I dont know about expendable listview.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you problem is like this then you can see this:

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

or

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-simple-expandable-listview.html

Comment: Yes, I checked some tutorials but in my app, there is no facility like expand and collapse. Can you please help me solve problem with my current issue ?